# What's the bug in the following code?

Tags: c++, stl, boost, segmentation-fault

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

int main() {
  boost::array<int, 4> a = {45, 11, 67, 23};
  std::vector<int> v(a.begin(), a.end());
  std::vector<int> v2;
  std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v2.begin(), 
    boost::bind(std::multiplies<int>(), _1, 2));
  std::copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

When run, this gives a creepy segmentation fault. Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @Tom: Sorry but I am C++ newbie; it'd take a while for me to be familiar with all the edge cases in STL.

Comment: what's a 'creepy segmentation fault'?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`v2` has a size of zero when you call `transform`.  You either need to resize `v2` so that it has at least as many elements as `v` before the call to `transform`:

```
v2.resize(v.size());
```

or you can use `std::back_inserter` in the call to `transform`:

```
std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(v2), boost::bind(std::multiplies<int>(), _1, 2));
```

Comment: And best is probably to `v2.reserve(v.size())` first before a `transform`.